# Where is sulfur found when using Railcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Title says it all, really.

When using [Railcraft](http://railcraft.wikispaces.com), where can sulfur be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some nuke-based prospecting and using the hints provided by SaintWacko, I've managed to find the answer:

Sulfur spawns near underground lava lakes in ExteremeHills biomes.

Plentiful when present, but the conditions can be hard to come by.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a few hints that may point you in the right direction. From the patch notes:

> NEW: Sulfur and Saltpeter, in the hills yellow and hot, and in the
>   darkness beneath the parched sky.

From a list of coding thanks for another mod:

> CovertJaguar - For helping me with sulfur generation around lava and
>   Railcraft compatibility!

These make me think that you may find sulfur around pools of lava on the surface.

Comment: There are sulfurs and sulphurs in at least three different mods :/ Railcraft, Forestry, and Thermal Expansion, which that particular one is from.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun a bit on that one. Posted it here, went back to close the tab and noticed it said Thermal Expansion instead of Railcraft. Found some new info though, hopefully it will help.